Identify Doctor Who episode with the source of all evil
This is not from the classical series: I am quite sure David Tennant was the Doctor; it was probably in two parts.
In this episode(s) the TARDIS lands, if I remember correctly, in a human colony far from Earth near a black hole (?); I remember they use Oods as slaves.
At some point the Oods' eyes turn red: they become evil and start attacking people.
The Doctor understands that the reason for this behavior is deep inside a cave in that planet; he understands that there is THE EVIL, the source of all the evil in the universe and that it is trying to escape.

Did you just ask someone to source the source of all evil?

The Ood have only appeared in 8 episodes... it wouldn't have been hard to check them.

The episode you're looking for is actually a two-parter (Thanks Gallifreyan!). It's composed of The Impossible Planet and The Satan Pit.



The episodes feature The Beast (a being specifically identified as being the inspiration for all devilish characters in myth) stuck, bound, inside a planet. The Beast uses the Ood to communicate with The Doctor and other inhabitants.
I won't spoil it for you, but things go awry and the black hole comes into play.

Nitpick - the first episode of this 2-story arc is called "The Impossible Planet"

Switched the video out to one that won't literally spoil the plot in the first five seconds.

@Gallifreyan Noted! Thanks!
